# Hi there, Im trying to create a table using SQL developer and it's providing me with an error message saying "invalid data type"

Tags: mysql, sql, database

It doesn't allow me to successful create the table because it has an invalid datatype.

w3Schools

```
CREATE TABLE Day_Care_Resident ( 
    PatientNO INT, 
    Arrival_Time time, 
    Collection_Time time, 
    Address VARCHAR2(50), 
    PhoneNumber number, 
    SocialWorker VARCHAR2(25), 
    WeekdaysAtHome VARCHAR2(10),

    PRIMARY KEY (PatientNO), 
    FOREIGN KEY (PatientNO) REFERENCES PATIENT (PatientNO) 
);
```

Comment: Which column, which data type?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `number` is not a data type in MySQL.  I would recommend storing phone numbers as strings, because they are not really numbers.

Comment: I've solved it, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentionned SQL Developer in the title of your question, so I suspect that you are running Oracle, not mysql as tagged in your question.

> Arrival_Time time, Collection_Time time

There is no `time` datatype in Oracle. You probably want to use `date` instead, so you can correctly represent these points in time.

---

On the other hand, if you are running mysql, then datatype issues are:

- the `varchar2` datatype, does not exist in mysql (this is an Oracle specific datatype). You can just replace that with `varchar`
- the `number` datatype does not exist either; you can use `numeric` instead

Comment: Thanks I've used the  date data type to represent the arrival time and collection time